# Highcharts draw (and remove) glyphs on the chart

Tags: highcharts, jscript

I want to add annotations to Highcharts graphs. For instance, in a bubble chart, in some cases I want to add a bit of text on top of the bubble. I have done this by using the [chart.renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer.text).

```
renderElem = chart.renderer.text(
  "Glyph", 
  point.plotX, 
  point.plotY + chart.plotTop
).add();
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g446zfzk/2/).

However, when that series is disabled then the rendered text remains on the same fixed spot. So I would like to clear the text drawn with the renderer and re-draw it. I can use 
plotOptions.bubble.events.legendItemClick to get the proper event. But I cannot find in the documentation how exactly to clear the renderer.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'normal'
  },
  bubble: {
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function () {
        var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
        // how can I clear the renderer text?
        //  rendererElem ????
      }
    }
  },
  allowPointSelect: false
},
```

Now, there are two questions:

1. How can I clear the text/shapes created with the renderer?
2. Is there another way to add a bit of text or indicator or glyph next to a point in the graph (besides using the renderer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to variable (which keep rendererd object) and call destroy() method.